# GitHub Copilot chat in Visual Studio only shows a busy circle

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I am using Copilot in Visual Studio 2022 (not VS Code). Using Copilot itself has worked fantastically.
I recently saw Copilot chat available as an extension, after installing the chat window just shows  a busy circle. [image: Copiloit chat busy circle]

The only thing I have tried is just let it run (all day) hoping it would eventually resolve.
I am behind a company firewall which could be blocking something however, I did not receive any notifications that it was getting blocked. I understand this product is still beta-y, however has anyone else experienced this?